# Download a file from a onclick button using Selenium and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm

SO, I'm trying to download a file into a specific directory while using Selenium with nodeJS to trigger the download. Here is the code I have to click the button itself:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const assert = require('chai').assert;
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
     .forBrowser('chrome')
     .add_argument("")
     .build();

driver.get(url);

driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        expect(title).to.equal(title);
    });
});
driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
    driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');
    driver.sleep(300);
    driver.findElement(By.className('button col-md-2 download-button')).click();
})
```

My issue is that Selenium and the web driver seem to download into a unknown/inaccessible location. If anyone knows how to solve this issue if would be appreciated.

```
Chrome Driver Version = 2.32.498537 
npm Selenium-Webdriver Version = 3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the download location by doing something like:

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments(“download.default_directory”,”/path/to/download”);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
     .forBrowser('chrome')
     .withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities())
     .build();
```